# I am having problem installing protocol buffer on windows?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc

I am having issue while installing the protobuf for Python in Windows. The version for Protobuf is 3.8.0.Among the mentioned below step I am not being able to figure out the third step of Build C++ code or install binaries. Can anyone explain?

The readme states:

1) Make sure you have Python 2.4 or newer. If in doubt, run:

$ python -V

2) If you do not have setuptools installed, note that it will be downloaded and installed automatically as soon as you run setup.py. If you would rather install it manually, you may do so by following the instructions on this page:

http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/EasyInstall#installation-instructions

3) Build the C++ code, or install a binary distribution of protoc. If you install a binary distribution, make sure that it is the same version as this package. If in doubt, run:

$ protoc --version

4) Run the tests:

$ python setup.py test
If some tests fail, this library may not work correctly on your system. Continue at your own risk.

Please note that there is a known problem with some versions of Python on Cygwin which causes the tests to fail after printing the error: "sem_init: Resource temporarily unavailable". This appears to be a bug either in Cygwin or in Python: http://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2005-07/msg01378.html We do not know if or when it might me fixed. We also do not know how likely it is that this bug will affect users in practice.

5) Install:

$ python setup.py install
This step may require superuser privileges. NOTE: To use C++ implementation, you need to install C++ protobuf runtime library of the same version and export the environment variable before this step. See the "C++ Implementation" section below for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I found the solution . Just need to go to that release page and scroll down to the bottom and there is the protoc.zip at the bottom of assets section.